# PHP if time is not passed

Tags: php, if-statement, time

I have an XML file with a date and time in it on this format: YYYYMMDDHH
It are 4 digit year, 2 digit month, 2 digit day and 2 digit hour.

How is it possible to make an if/else statement based on this variable.

I have tried this code, but is doesnt work for me.

```
if( strtotime($validtime) < strtotime('now') ) {
echo "display forecast";
}
else{
echo "hide forecast";
}
```

Where $validtime is off course the timestring.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post the value of `$validtime`?

Comment: @Askanison4 it's a `YYYYMMDDHH` so right now in NY it would be `2014042812`

Comment: I have tried this here: http://writecodeonline.com/php/ and it worked just fine. Maybe I am missing something.

Comment: It might need to be formatted to something like mm/dd/yyyy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`strtotime()` does not natively recognize the `YYYYMMDDHH` format so you should manually append minutes and seconds like this:

```
if( strtotime($validtime.'0000') < strtotime('now') ) {
    echo "display forecast";
}
else{
    echo "hide forecast";
}
```

Please note that the code above will almost always enter the `if()` statement because `strtotime('now')` produces seconds so something like this will likely be suitable:

```
if( strtotime($validtime.'0000') < strtotime(date('Y-m-d H:00:00')) ) {
```

Answer (score 0):

The YYYYMMDDHH format is not recognized with strtotimer(), so you will need to reformat the $validtime variable.  Something like this should work:

```
if(strtotime(substr($validtime,4,2)."/".substr($validtime,6,2)."/".substr($validtime,0,4)." ".substr($validtime,8,2).":00") < strtotime('now') ) {
    echo "display forecast";
}
else{
    echo "hide forecast";
}
```